# Mysql query for difference of group sum of two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to get the difference of sum of two columns obtained by GROUP BY clause for which I'm using this query

```
"SELECT " + KEY_NAME + ", SUM("
            + KEY_COL1 + ") AS s1, SUM(" + KEY_COL2 + ") AS s2, "
            + KEY_ID + " FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " + COUNT
            + " BETWEEN " + start + " AND " + end + " GROUP BY "
            + KEY_NAME + " HAVING (s1 - s2) < 0 ORDER BY " + KEY_NAME
            + " ASC"
```

I want all the fields satisfying the above condition to implement it in my android cursor adapter. It doesn't give any error but it shows both sides of results (where s1 - s2 > 0 & s1 - s2 < 0) for some reason unknown to me. Basically it gives the same result as

```
"SELECT " + KEY_NAME + ", SUM("
            + KEY_COL1 + ") AS s1, SUM(" + KEY_COL2 + ") AS s2, "
            + KEY_ID + " FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_COUNT
            + " BETWEEN " + start + " AND " + end + " GROUP BY "
            + KEY_NAME + " ORDER BY " + KEY_NAME
            + " ASC"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Further I want the sum of s1-s2 for all the fields satisfying the above condition. How can I do that?

**Edit:**

The above code serves the purpose. But coming to my second question.

I want sum(sum(s1) - sum(s2)). Basically I want sum of all the 'diff' in Bohemian answer.

Comment: This is almost unreadable. Can we ditch the non-mysql code for now?

Comment: AH! THE HORROR! why do people does not use prepared statements or similar constructs?

Answer (score 2):

After removing all the string building code noise, the error was obvious:

```
SELECT
    KEY_NAME,
    SUM(KEY_COL1) AS s1,
    SUM(KEY_COL2) AS s2,
    SUM(KEY_COL1) - SUM(KEY_COL2) as diff, -- ### added this to get diff
    KEY_ID
FROM DATABASE_TABLE
WHERE COUNT BETWEEN start AND end
GROUP BY KEY_NAME, KEY_ID -- ### Added KEY_ID to group by clause
HAVING (s1 - s2) < 0
ORDER BY KEY_NAME ASC
```

You weren't grouping by all non-aggregate columns: You must add `KEY_ID` to the group by clause.

On any other database, this would explode, but mysql allows it but returns a random row for every unique combination of non-aggregate columns that *are* listed in the group by.

I also added a column that calculates the difference in sums as you wanted.

Comment: Hey, thanks but that query worked. I was doing some silly error because of all the 'noise'. But can you please explain me the reason for using KEY_ID in GROUP BY?

Comment: Because I think when we use GROUP BY KEY_NAME, it groups all the elements with same KEY_NAME so won't using KEY_ID add to errors?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using

```
"SELECT SUM(s2) - SUM(s1) FROM ( " + "SELECT " + KEY_NAME + ", SUM("
            + KEY_COL1 + ") AS s1, SUM(" + KEY_COL2 + ") AS s2, "
            + KEY_ID + " FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " + COUNT
            + " BETWEEN " + start + " AND " + end + " GROUP BY "
            + KEY_NAME + " HAVING (s1 - s2) < 0 ORDER BY " + KEY_NAME
            + " ASC)"
```

Thanks everyone.